# Advice on relay set-up

Tags: arduino, relay, netduino

I'm trying to build a Christmas light show, using a netduino (arduino clone). There are plenty of tutorials on the web, however they always lends themselves to US power supplies. Could someone please recommend to me the best way to switch a 10A 240V power suppy (x8 for different lights) via the 5v arduino supply? I can't cut into the lights themselves, so I would be switching an extension cable, hence the high amperage. I have found suitable relays online however they are rated at a 12v switching supply.

Thanks!!

Comment: I don't get your point about switching an extension cable requiring more current. Your lights will draw the same amount of current whether they're plugged directly into the wall or through an extension cord. Also, to produce the same amount of light, a light string designed for and used at 240 V should draw half as much current as one designed for and used at 120 V.

Comment: @ThePhoton - He probably meant high voltage.

Comment: If Lewis can't get a relay which handles 10 amps he could also label the output of his circuit with a warning "X A max." and include a corresponding fuse (does never hurt to have one). An nice touch would also be to switch both wires to make sure that the hot wire is switched off in every case.

Comment: I assume he's powering all lights through one extension cable so the total current for all is going through one point - if he controlled it at the individual strings of lights it would be less current.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of 5V relays available.  The trick is getting ones that switch a high enough current.

If you can't find one, then use a 12V one and power it with 12V.

Whether you're using a 5V or a 12V relay you'll require something between the Netduino and the relay to be able to provide enough current to switch the relay - be that a transistor, or a chip like the ULN2803.  Either of these can switch 12V as easily as 5V.

If you want to use the ULN2803 with the Arduino/Netduino I have designed [a handy shield you can etch yourself with Toner Transfer](http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/node/10).

The other option (which will be much quieter, albeit at more cost) would be to use a "Solid State Relay".  This is essentially an opto-coupled triac which does the same job as a relay but without any moving parts (except photons).  These, being opto-coupled, use about the same current to switch as an LED uses to light up, so can be linked direct to the Arduino/Netduino with nothing more than the normal current limiting resistor for an LED.

---

Added RM:

Majenko's 'shield' implements this circuit. Its a good useful universal driver circuit. Note the connection of pin 9 to V+. This connects the on chip catch diodes to supply to dissipate stored energy in the relay coils when they are turned off. If you don't make this connection you will end up with an exciting high voltage generator - possibly a short lived one.
 (Circuit from[(here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread156365.html)) which does not give any other detail.

[image]

Comment: A little more info on solid-state relays: [see this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21776/what-kind-of-transistor-do-i-need-to-amplify-an-arduinos-pwm-outputs/21833#21833)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a transistor.
Or maybe a smaller 5V DC powered relay with the desired output rating.

Comment: Welcome to Electrical Engineering!  I'm confused as to how you propose to use a transistor or smaller 5VDC relay to switch 10A at 240V, and the OP almost certainly won't find what they need in this answer (yet!)  See [How to Answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) for some additional suggestions.  In brief, this space should contain the how and why of this solution, not just an option for the OP to explore.  Thanks!